# Function ellipticAdd to add points belonging to an elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + a\,x^2 + b\,x$

Tags: algebra, group-theory

In the [EllipticLog](http://https:%20//%20reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticLog.html) WRI web page, there is a function called`"ellipticMultiply` defined as:

```
 ellipticMultiply[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, {a_, b_}] := 
   Module[{s = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1), x3, y3}, 
     x3 = s^2 - x1 - x2 - a; 
     y3 = -y1 + s (x1 - x3); 
     {x3, y3}]
```

to multiply points that belong to an elliptic curve of the form $y^2 = x^3 + a\,x^2 + b\,x$.  Is there a function (call it `ellipticAdd`) to add such points, and if not, could you provide one?

Comment: There are [two Q&A on elliptic curve addition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=elliptic+curve+addition) on site already that have code for adding points.

Comment: @Moo & Michael E2;  Indeed; using the EllipticLog and EllipticExp functions to define addition is what I needed.  Thank you for your help!